# VC with TableView nested in CollectionViewCell, how can i pass data from TableView back to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nested, tableview, collectionview

Within my `CharacterSelectionVC` I have a TableView that is nested in a CollectionView. Each CollectionViewCell represents a part (arms, eyes, pupils, etc.) of my character. Each tableViewCell represents an alternate image for the character part. To display the part's name, I attached a label to the tableViewCell.

***After, selecting a tableView's cell, how can I pass its label data to my CharacterSelectionVC?*** I tried creating an instance of the view controller in the table view and passing the label input into the instance's property but when i `print(mouthSelectionCharacterModel)`from CharacterSelectionVC , the array comes back empty. Apologies upfront, if i didn't correctly follow any coding best practices.

**Visual Representation of TableView nested in CollectionView**
[image]

**CollectionViewCell & TableView:**

```
class CharacterInventoryCVCellFinal: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var dataArray2: [String]?
    var mouthSelectionFinal: [String] = []
    let characterSelectionVC = CharacterSelectionViewController()   

    @IBOutlet var flexAnimationCustomElements: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    struct PropertyKeys {
          static let tableViewCellID = "tbCell"
      }
     
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray2?.count ?? 0
       }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PropertyKeys.tableViewCellID, for: indexPath)
            
        cell.textLabel!.text = dataArray2?[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        let optionChoice = indexPath.row
        print(optionChoice)
        
        var str8 = dataArray2?[indexPath.item]
        mouthSelectionFinal.append(str8!)
        
        characterSelectionVC.mouthSelectionCharacterModel = mouthSelectionFinal
                         
        print(mouthSelectionFinal)  
        
        }
}
```

**ViewController & CollectionView:**

```
class CharacterSelectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    //MARK: Container for collectionView cell's labels
    var elementsForSelection: [String] = ["mouth",  "head", "hair", "pupils", "eyes", "eyelids", "eyeBrows", "ears", "neck", "torso", "shoulders", "arms", "hands", "nose"]

    //MARK: Container for user selected tableView cell's label
    var mouthSelectionCharacterModel: [String] = []


@IBOutlet var characterElementSelectionCollection: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func touchSelectCharacterBt(_ sender: Any) {
        applyCharacter()
    }


       func  applyCharacter() {
       print(mouthSelectionCharacterModel)

       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rawData4.count
       }
    
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PropertyKeys.collectionViewCellID, for: indexPath) as! CharacterInventoryCVCellFinal
        
        let dataArray = rawData4[indexPath.row]
        cellA.updateCellWith2(row: dataArray)

        cellA.flexAnimationCustomElements.text = self.elementsForSelection[indexPath.item]
        
        return cellA
        
      }
    
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        elementChoice = indexPath.item
        print(elementChoice)
        
     }
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
    
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        
        characterElementSelectionCollection.delegate = self
        characterElementSelectionCollection.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(characterElementSelectionCollection)
        
        let dict =  CloneAnimation_20200907.finalize(imageFileNames: characterSVCImageFileNames)
        
        mouthSelection = dict["mouthAngry"]!
        headSelection = dict["head1"]!
        hairSelection = dict["hair"]!
        pupilsSelection = dict["pupilsLeft"]!
        eyesSelection = dict["eyeLeft"]!
        eyeLidsSelection = dict["eyeLidLeft"]!
        eyeBrowsSelection = dict["eyeBrowRight"]!
        earsSelection = dict["earRight"]!
        neckSelection = dict ["neck"]!
        torsoSelection = dict["torso"]!
        shouldersSelection = dict["shoulderLeft"]!
        armsSelection = dict["armLowerLeft"]!
        handsSelection = dict["handLeft"]!
        noseSelection = dict["nose"]!
        
        rawData4 = [mouthSelection, headSelection, hairSelection, pupilsSelection, eyesSelection, eyeLidsSelection, eyeBrowsSelection, earsSelection, neckSelection, torsoSelection, shouldersSelection, armsSelection, handsSelection, noseSelection]
        
  
    }

}
```

**Extensions**

```
//MARK: To help pass along data for tableView
extension CharacterInventoryCVCellFinal{
    func updateCellWith2(row: [String]) {
        self.dataArray2 = row
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewController is managing the collection view.

Your CollectionViewCell is managing the table view.

So, when you get `didSelectRowAt` in your CollectionViewCell, it needs to tell the Controller what was selected, and let the controller update the data.

Here's a quick example...

**Simple Struct for the data**

```
struct BodyStruct {
    var title: String = ""
    var parts: [String] = []
    var selectedPart: Int = -1
}
```

**Single label table view cell**

```
class PartsCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "partsCell"
    
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

**Collection View cell with embedded table view**

```
class EmbedTableCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    static let identifier: String = "embedCell"

    var callBack: ((EmbedTableCollectionCell, IndexPath) -> ())?
    
    var theData: BodyStruct = BodyStruct()
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.textColor = .blue
        
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        let c1 = titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 260.0)
        let c2 = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 132.0)
        c1.priority = .required - 1
        c2.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            c1,
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            c2,
            
        ])
        
        tableView.register(PartsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PartsCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    
    func fillData(_ st: BodyStruct) {
        self.theData = st
        tableView.reloadData()
        titleLabel.text = theData.title
        if theData.selectedPart > -1 {
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: theData.selectedPart, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        } else {
            if let pth = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: pth, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.parts.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PartsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PartsCell
        c.theLabel.text = theData.parts[indexPath.row]
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // tell the controller a part was selected
        callBack?(self, indexPath)
    }
}
```

**Example view controller**

```
class EmbedTestVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var myData: [BodyStruct] = []
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let infoLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 12
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)

        infoLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        infoLabel.text = "Selected:"
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            infoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])

        collectionView.register(EmbedTableCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: EmbedTableCollectionCell.identifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // some sample data
        let titles: [String] = [
            "head", "hair", "eyes", "ears", "nose", "arms", "hands",
        ]
        let parts: [[String]] = [
            ["round", "pointy", "square",],
            ["long", "short", "bald",],
            ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "cyan", "magenta",],
            ["Vulkan", "dangling", "attached",],
            ["pixie", "bulbous", "crooked",],
            ["tattooed", "hairy",],
            ["gloves", "mittens", "bare",],
        ]
        for (t, a) in zip(titles, parts) {
            let d = BodyStruct(title: t, parts: a)
            myData.append(d)
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100.0)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: EmbedTableCollectionCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! EmbedTableCollectionCell
        
        c.fillData(myData[indexPath.item])
        
        c.callBack = { [weak self] cell, partsPath in
            guard let self = self,
                  let idx = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            else { return }

            // update data
            self.myData[idx.item].selectedPart = partsPath.row
            
            self.infoLabel.text = "Selected: \(self.myData[idx.item].title) / \(self.myData[idx.item].parts[partsPath.row])"
        }

        return c
    }
    
}
```

When you run that it will look like this - and when you select a "part" the label at the bottom will be updated with the selection. The data `.selectedPart` property will also be updated, so each table view will maintain its previously selected row:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks @DanMog I'll review your code my next morning and follow up with feedback.

Comment: @DanMog your code adjustments and additions worked great! Adding in the structure helped a lot as well. I'm pretty sure I couldn't have solved the callback method nor the fill data function on my own, so thank you! I definitely learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your cell classes you can have a delegate, and you can send your pass your data using that delegate methods.

[image: Basic Diagram]

Hope it helps.